# Karatsuba multiplication for $x = 123 , y = 100$

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

Given the numbers $x = 123$ and $y = 100$ how to apply the Karatsuba algorithm to multiply these numbers ?

The formula is

```
xy=10^n(ac)+10^n/2(ad+bc)+bd
```

As I understand $n = 3$ (number of digits) and I tried writing the numbers as

```
x = 10*12+3 , y = 10*10 +0 thus a = 12 , b = 3 , c = 10 , d = 0
```

or

```
x = 100*1+23 , y = 100*1 +0 thus a = 1 , b = 23 , c = 1 , d = 0
```

I looked at some explanations of the algorithm and tried it successfully for other numbers , but I don't know how to solve it in this particular case.

Is this example part of a more general case of the algorithm (like 3-digit numbers)? I found a question that may be related ([Karatsuba multiplication with integers of size 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220419/karatsuba-multiplication-with-integers-of-size-3)) and from the answer I gather that it's impossible , so is it that Karatsuba can't multiply $2$ numbers of $3$-digits or is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

What you have writtem is almost correct. 
The Karatsuba Algorithm expands the multiplication of $123$ and $100$ to
$$\begin{aligned}
(12\times 10+3)(10\times10+0)&= 10^2\times(12\times10) + 10^1\times (12\times0 + 3 \times 10) + 3\times 10\\
&= 12000 + 300 + 0\\
&= 12300
\end{aligned}$$

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) describes the algorithm and how it is used to multiply integers of any length. The only caveat is that the two numbers being multiplied are of the same length.

Comment: This seems correct. I think my confusion is because of x=10^n*a+b , so in this case we have x = 10^1*12+3 thus n = 1 and n/2 = 0 , so I think I was using this n in the formula. Is there no relation between this n and the n from the formula ? and when dividing an odd number in halves I should just make a bigger than b ?

Comment: You don't choose the value of $n$, you choose the the value of $n/2$. Your formula would be better written as $xy=10^{2n}(ac)+10^n(ad+bc)+bd$, so the problem of halving an odd number doesn't arise.

Answer (score 0):

$xy=123\cdot 100$

$(12\cdot 10+3)(10\cdot 10+0)$

$xy=10^n(ac)+10^n/2(ad+bc)+bd$, where $n=2
a=12, b=3, c=10, d=0$

subcategory 1:

$ac=12\cdot 10 = 120$
$bd=3\cdot 0 = 0$
$ad+bc= (12+3)(10+0)=150-120-0 = 30..$

$120\cdot 10^2 + 30\cdot 10^1 + 0$

subcategory 2:

$12\cdot 10$

$a=1,
b=2,
c=1,
d=0$

$ac=1$
$bd=0$
$ad+bc=(a+b)(b+d)-ac-bd$
$ad+bc= (1+2)(1+0)-1-0 = 2$

$ac\cdot 10^2 + (ad+bc)\cdot 10 + bd =120..$

Comment: Please use MathJax to increase the readability of your answer.

Comment: Next time please add dollar signs in both sides of your mathematical expressions, it makes everything look way smoother and readable. You can click on "edit" and check out how I edited your answer ;)

Comment: I am even unsure if done everything correctly so please read through the edited version to see if I messed something up. Especially with exponents